# Create a view in SnowFlake dynamically using JSON string

Tags: json, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create dynamic views from JSON string data

```
create or replace view schema.vw_tablename copy grants as  
 SELECT
 v:Duration::int Duration,
 v:Connectivity::string Connectivity
 ...
from public.tablename
```

This is a kind of manual view for one of the table but i want to code in generic way so that i will pass the table name which is having JSON data and view will be created and output will be tabular format.

Comment: I think you're in for a challenge here.  Since JSON doesn't have data types and can be nested with all sorts of arrays and sub-attributes, you'd need a pretty robust script outside of Snowflake to determine the data types, the depth of your FLATTEN statements, etc. in order to truly create a dynamic view.  If your JSON is just a list of attributes, that'd help, but you'd still need something to evaluate data types before creating your view.

Comment: Also, JSON data might be dynamic as well, which means that any view should be regenerated every time the JSON data is updated, otherwise you risk missing out on new attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to have the view created in snowflake driven by data (as compared to using a tool to create the views client side, which we do in our company) I think you only hope will be [stored procedures](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html). In the detailed [usage](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html) doc's it reminds you DDL operations commits the current transaction (which is always good to remember) but also implies that you can do DDL, which is what you are asking. Which means you should be able to write some javascript that builds the `create view` command you are want based on data handed to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice 2 part blog that handles this requirement. Similar to what is mentioned in Simeon Pilgrim's answer, the blog also uses a Stored Proc to generate the View. Albeit it does so using Snowflake SQL.

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/automating-snowflakes-semi-structured-json-data-handling/

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/automating-snowflakes-semi-structured-json-data-handling-part-2/

Comment: There's a follow-up to that blog post here that makes a few improvements: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Automating-Schema-on-Read-for-Records-Containing-Both-Semi-Structured-and-Structured-Data-in-Snowflake